# message: move The DestinationId parameter is missing

Tags: php, post, microsoft-graph-api, copy

I want to move mails (copy or move), I use
Microsoft\Graph\Graph , guzzlehttp/guzzle and php

I am missing the `DestinationId` parameter

here is the query I am using

```
$graph->createCollectionRequest("POST","/users/xxx@xxxx.com/mailFolders/$inbox_id/childFolders/$folder_id/messages/$message_id/move/")->execute();
```

and I don't know where to put `DestinationId`.

here is the error code I got

```
{
  "code":"ErrorInvalidParameter",
  "message":"The value of the parameter 'DestinationId' is empty."
}
```

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-move?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body you need to send this parameter as part of the request body.

Comment: And according to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/docs/Examples.md#send-an-email, you need to use the `attachBody` method, and apparently pass the data as an array.

Answer (score 1):

I found
$mailBody = array( "DestinationId" => "$message_id");

$graph->createCollectionRequest("POST","/users/xxx@xxxx.com/mailFolders/$inbox_id/childFolders/$folder_id/messages/$message_id/move/")->execute()
->attachBody($mailBody)
->execute();